# Scala: Thread safe mutable lazy Iterator with append

Tags: scala

For an immutable flavour, `Iterator` does the job.

```
val x = Iterator.fill(100000)(someFn)
```

Now I want to implement a mutable version of `Iterator`, with three guarantees:

- thread-safe on all transformations(`fold`, `foldLeft`, ..) and `append`
- lazy evaluated
- traversable only once! Once used, an object from this `Iterator` should be destroyed.

Is there an existing implementation to give me these guarantees? Any library or framework example would be great.

**Update**

To illustrate the desired behaviour.

```
class SomeThing {}
class Test(val list: Iterator[SomeThing]) {
   def add(thing: SomeThing): Test = {
      new Test(list ++ Iterator(thing))
   }
}
(new Test()).add(new SomeThing).add(new SomeThing);
```

In this example, `SomeThing` is an expensive construct, it needs to be lazy.

Re-iterating over `list` is never required, `Iterator` is a good fit.

This is supposed to asynchronously and lazily sequence 10 million `SomeThing` instances without depleting the executor(a cached thread pool executor) or running out of memory.

Comment: How would it be allowed to mutate? can't answer this until we know how map, flat map, etc should work lazily.

Comment: @wheaties Exclusively with `append`. That would be the only mutation.

Comment: Give me 40min to get to work. I've got an idea.

Comment: @wheaties Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: this is how I sometimes pass the morning. It picks me up and lets me walk into work feeling like I got something done in the day.

Comment: @wheaties I can't say I don't know the feeling. The project is OSS(async type safe Scala DSL for Cassandra). If you want more mornings like this I'd be happy to give you the git repo :)

Comment: We're using Cassandra at my new job, though not with Scala. I'd love the repo but I need to make sure that the "We own all your ideas" clause does not apply.

Comment: It's standard Apache V2 open source license. Contributions are listed, all standard OSS workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a mutable Iterator for this, just daisy-chain the immutable form:

```
class SomeThing {}

case class Test(val list: Iterator[SomeThing]) {
  def add(thing: => SomeThing) = Test(list ++ Iterator(thing))
}

(new Test()).add(new SomeThing).add(new SomeThing)
```

Although you don't really need the extra boilerplate of `Test` here:

```
Iterator(new SomeThing) ++ Iterator(new SomeThing)
```

Note that `Iterator.++` takes a by-name param, so the `++` operation is already lazy.

You might also want to try this, to avoid building intermediate Iterators:

```
Iterator.continually(new SomeThing) take 2
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't know the size in advance, then I'll often use a tactic like this:

```
def mkSomething = if(cond) Some(new Something) else None
Iterator.continually(mkSomething) takeWhile (_.isDefined) map { _.get }
```

The trick is to have your generator function wrap its output in an Option, which then gives you a way to flag that the iteration is finished by returning `None`

Of course... If you're *really* pushing out the boat, you can even use the dreaded `null`:

```
def mkSomething = if(cond) { new Something } else null
Iterator.continually(mkSomething) takeWhile (_ != null)
```

Comment: Okay, I added another possibility for you

Comment: Is there any good reason why the generator function can't be passed as an argument to `Iterator.continually`?

Comment: Okay, added a solution for that problem too :)

Comment: I can only work within the stated constraints of the posted question :)  If you can explain why it isn't suitable, there may be a far better fit using e.g. `Future`s or the `Observable` class from RxJava.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to hide the fact that the iterator is mutable but at the same time allow it to grow mutably. What I'm going to propose is the same sort of trick I've used to speed up `:::` in the past:

```
 abstract class AppendableIterator[A] extends Iterator[A]{
   protected var inner: Iterator[A]
   def hasNext = inner.hasNext
   def next() = inner next ()

   def append(that: Iterator[A]) = synchronized{
     inner = new JoinedIterator(inner, that)
   }
 }

 //You might need to add some more things, this is a skeleton
 class JoinedIterator[A](first: Iterator[A], second: Iterator[A]) extends Iterator[A]{
   def hasNext = first.hasNext || second.hasNext
   def next() = if(first.hasNext) first next () else if(second.hasNext) second next () else Iterator.next()
 }
```

So what you're really doing is leaving the `Iterator` at whatever place in its iteration you might have it while still preserving the thread safety of the append by "joining" another `Iterator` in non-destructively. You avoid the need to recompute the two together because you never actually force them through a `CanBuildFrom`.

This is also a generalization of just adding one item. You can always wrap some `A` in an `Iterator[A]` of one element if you so choose.

Comment: @flavian I'll take a look tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [`mutable.ParIterable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParIterable) in the `collection.parallel` package?

To access an iterator over elements you can do something like

```
val x = ParIterable.fill(100000)(someFn).iterator
```

From the docs:
`Parallel operations are implemented with divide and conquer style algorithms that parallelize well. The basic idea is to split the collection into smaller parts until they are small enough to be operated on sequentially.`

...

`The higher-order functions passed to certain operations may contain side-effects. Since implementations of bulk operations may not be sequential, this means that side-effects may not be predictable and may produce data-races, deadlocks or invalidation of state if care is not taken. It is up to the programmer to either avoid using side-effects or to use some form of synchronization when accessing mutable data.`

Comment: I overlooked the append. My bad :-) But they should be available in `ParSeq` for example. I'm not sure I follow your definition of 'thread-safe' then. The parallel collections should be 'safe' when traversing elements. Meaning that the function `someFn` only executes once per element and that the result is summed in a 'safe' manor. If you want the entire data-collection to be thread-safe, and not just the execution (although I don't understand why you would need that), I would suggest looking at the Java api. For instance the java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue or similar.

Comment: ParSeq wouldn't be lazy then. Nor would `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.